# Dynamically adding an array of objects to Vue (reactivity problem)

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

I know that in order for an object or array to be reactive in Vue its properties have to be defined on the root data structure.

What's the best way to add an array of objects to a pre-existing variable defined on the root data structure, **and make every property of every element in that array reactive**?

I have tried looping through the array and adding each to the root data model, ie:

```
  these_terms.forEach(function(term, idx) {
    term.selected = false;
    Vue.set(vm.game.set,idx,term);
  });
```

However, Vue does still not respond to the "term.selected" property when it is later changed.

Is there a better way of achieving my aim, or do I need to resort to $forceUpdate? (the manual says that in 99% of cases using $forceUpdate, you're doing something wrong, hence this post)

Comment: Can you include more code? (For example: your component data)

Comment: I solved the issue by pushing each item to the array instead of trying to assign the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

On your parent component, do the following:

1. Make a data attribute with a empty array starting out
2. Make a button that calls a method
3. In that method, push to the empty array.

Example of step 3

```
    methods: {
      _addGroup: function() {
        let result = {
          id: this.wizardGroups.length + 1,
          name: '',
        };
        this.wizardGroups.push(result);
      },
```

If you need to append additional properties afterwards, you can loop through the array of objects and apply `Vue.set()` as well

Comment: I was in a similar scenario, and I've used Vue.set() successfully too.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry if I understand it wrong but why dont you import the array and bring it into a Vue Data Variable?

```
import xx from "xxxx.js"

export default {
    data() {
        return {
           y: xx
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: The JSON is being fetched from an external API and I don't necessarily know what structure the data will be.
P.S. The downvote wasn't from me